# Android SDK cannot be found

Tags: flutter

When I run flutter doctor, this is what is says:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.6, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale
    en-CN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I have downloaded android 12 from android studio, so I don't know what could be causing this problem. I didn't download it to a custom location, it is just sitting in my applications.

I tried looking for an answer on StackOverflow and online, but their problem is different from mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the terminal: flutter config --android-sdk

For  use the path where is your Android SDK located. In most cases it is "C:\Users\yourSystemUsername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

Answer (score 0):

First, find the location of your android SDK. If you cant, download again to custom location using `SDK Manager` from Android Studio.
My location looks like `C:\src\Android\SDK`

Now run the following command-> `flutter config --android-sdk "sdk-location"`

In my case, `flutter config --android-sdk "C:\src\Android\SDK"`

Your sdk file should look something like this
[image]